# linux c: sysinfo get bad memory values

Tags: c, linux, sysinfo

I use `sysinfo` to get memory information. But the result seems to be wrong, as it isn't consistent with `/proc/meminfo`.

My codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

double megabyte = 1024 * 1024;

long
get_free_mem() {
    struct sysinfo si;
    int error = sysinfo(&si);
    printf("code error=%d\n",error);
    printf("available: %lu\n", si.freeram );
    printf("total: %lu\n", si.totalram);
    printf("mem_unit: %u \n", si.mem_unit);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    get_free_mem();
    return 0;
}
```

And output info is:

```
$./get_mem 
code error=0
available: 67733753856
total: 135443968000
mem_unit: 1
```

But `/proc/meminfo` shows:

```
$cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8388608 kB
MemFree:         4790464 kB
Buffers:               0 kB
Cached:          3042084 kB
```

And `free` shows:

```
$free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          8192       3513       4678          0          0       2970
-/+ buffers/cache:        543       7648
Swap:         1952          0       1952
```

It's obviously that something wrong in my codes, because I indeed don't have 135443968000 Bytes (almost 126 Gb, that's to large) on this server.

kernel:

```
Linux my_hostname 2.6.32-220.23.2.ali1113.el5.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jul 4 20:09:15 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Chanses are that you have same issue as one mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987636/sysinfo-system-call-not-returning-correct-freeram-value

Comment: Thanks for help. I have seen the linked question before. But not completely solve my confusion. What puzzled me is why my C codes get total memory size is 126GB, while the real value is 8GB.

Comment: Weird, because for me your snippet shows correct values. Also it is very strange to see `mem_unit: 1`. Usually, it must be `4096` Are you sure you're executing exactly the same code snipped as you've posted?

Comment: Yes, I execute exactly the above code. It's so strange that I tried the same code on another server, but it gave correct result and `mem_unit=4096` as you say. I had to dejectedly give up to find the reason , and now I read `/proc/meminfo` to get the memory info.

Answer (score 2):

The actual free memory available is:

```
Actual Free Memory = Free (39 MB) + Buffers (95) + Cached (3590) = 3,724 MB
```

That’s 95x more free memory than than we initially thought. Whenever there is free memory available, it takes it temporarily as cache memory and buffers. Linux reduces its cache / buffers usage and give the program what it wants.

See [this link](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2010/10/06/determining-free-memory-on-linux)  and [this link](http://www.faqs.org/docs/linux_admin/buffer-cache.html) for example and detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for reply! May be my statement is not clear enough. The problem is that, my C codes get total memory is 126GB, but the actual memory size is 8GB.

Comment: Linux needs lots of Memory and Whenever there is free memory available, it takes it temporarily as cache and cache is included in your memory details

Answer (score 2):

To get the correct memory value for say, total RAM, you need to multiply `si.total` and `si.memunit` and then divide by **1024**.

Same goes for Free RAM, Buffer RAM, etc.

EDIT: There is nothing wrong with memunit being set to **1**.

See also [C - sysinfo() returning bad values i686](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229415/c-sysinfo-returning-bad-values-i686)